# Does this second order linear ODE admits a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I am considering the following ODE in $x$:
$$x^2v''(x) + \alpha x v'(x) + \beta v(x)=0, $$
where $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$ and one of the boundary conditions says $v(0)=\gamma>0$. If I consider the change of variable $t = \log(x)$ and convert it into a linear ODE with constant coefficients, the condition $v(x)=0$ seems contradictory. I am wondering if this particular ODE admits a solution. I am looking for a transformation to convert it into a Whittaker-type ODE and seek for a solution after the transformation.

Comment: $v(x)=γ>0$ is not a boundary condition. Is there a limit for $x\to\infty$ or $x\to 0$ involved? Then that only works if $β=0$.

Comment: I made a typo. It should be $v(0)=\gamma>0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation